# Transform Statement from Access to DB2

Tags: ms-access, db2

> I have the following query that I am trying to understand and convert
>   it to a db2 format:

```
TRANSFORM Sum(Cases) AS SumOfCases
SELECT Process, Sum(Cases) AS total
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Process
PIVOT tbl.STATUS;
```

> Table has data like:
>
> Process    Status    Cases
>   a       Cancelled  14
>   a       Closed     179
>   b       Cancelled   20
>   b       Closed      30
>   b       Pending     10

How can I write that query to db2?
I tried the following query:

```
SELECT Process
, MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Cancelled' THEN CASES END) "Cancelled"
, MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Closed' THEN CASES END) "Closed"
, MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Pending' THEN CASES END) "Pending"
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Process;
```

> Since I do not have MS Access hence I am not confident that if I had done the right thing in db2 or not.
>
> Would appreciate if I could get some advice on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DB2 query works correctly in replicating Access's crosstab query except you missed the Total column. By the way any [aggregate function](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_11.0.0/com.ibm.db2z11.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_aggregatefunctionsintro.dita?lang=en) would work for your `CASE/WHEN` statements: `MIN()`, `MAX()`, `MEDIAN()`, `AVG()`, even `SUM()`:

```
SELECT Process
, SUM(CASES) AS "Total"
, MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Cancelled' THEN CASES END) AS "Cancelled"
, MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Closed' THEN CASES END) AS "Closed"
, MAX(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'Pending' THEN CASES END) AS "Pending"
FROM tbl
GROUP BY Process;
```

Comment: Thanks Parfait, I wanted to have a 2nd opinion from experts :).
Oh, I didn't notice that I forgot the aggregate function.